# Google Visualization Chart horizontal bar with target (vertical line

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I would like to set up a small and light chart using Google Visualizion chart.

The idea would be to have an horizontal bar chart (this I know how to do) BUT combined with a vertical line showing if a target is exceeded or not. 
The target can be different for each data.

In addition I would like to include an indicator (red/green) easily identifying who is under target and who is above (+ optinally a label just after the green/red dot).

[image]

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: you can use a [combo chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart), with a bar, line, and scatter series...

Comment: Do you think feasible to have horizontal bars using a combo chart? I did not manage to get it in Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, you can just use a `BarChart`,
and change the series type for the last two columns...

```
series: {
  1: {
    type: 'line'
  },
  2: {
    type: 'scatter'
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'x'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', id: 'bar'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', id: 'line'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', id: 'scatter'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['', 300, '300', 300, 800, '#4caf50'],
    ['', 600, '600', 600, 800, '#f44336'],
    ['', 200, '200', 200, 800, '#4caf50'],
    ['', 150, '150', 150, 800, '#f44336'],
  ]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      alwaysOutside: true,
      textStyle: {
        color: '#000000'
      }
    },
    colors: ['#9e9e9e', '#2196f3'],
    legend: 'none',
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        count: 0
      },
      textPosition: 'none'
    },
    series: {
      1: {
        lineWidth: 4,
        type: 'line'
      },
      2: {
        type: 'scatter'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

**EDIT**

to add custom labels next to the scatter points,
you can use chart method --> `getChartLayoutInterface()`

which has a method for --> `getBoundingBox(id)`
this can be used to find the position of a chart element.
where `id` is the string id of the point, in this format --> `point#series#row` -- `point#0#0`

on the chart's `'ready'` event, we can position custom labels next to the points.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function (sender) {
  var padding = 16;
  var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
  var containerBounds = chart.getContainer().getBoundingClientRect();

  for (var row = 0; row < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
    var pointBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('point#2#' + row);
    var dataLabel = document.createElement('span');
    dataLabel.className = 'data-label';
    dataLabel.innerHTML = 'Label ' + row;
    dataLabel.style.top = (containerBounds.top + pointBounds.top - (pointBounds.height / 2)) + 'px';
    dataLabel.style.left = (containerBounds.left + pointBounds.left + pointBounds.width + padding) + 'px';
    chart.getContainer().appendChild(dataLabel);
  }
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'x'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', id: 'bar'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', id: 'line'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', id: 'scatter'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['', 300, '300', 300, 800, '#4caf50'],
    ['', 600, '600', 600, 800, '#f44336'],
    ['', 200, '200', 200, 800, '#4caf50'],
    ['', 150, '150', 150, 800, '#f44336'],
  ]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      alwaysOutside: true,
      textStyle: {
        color: '#000000'
      }
    },
    colors: ['#9e9e9e', '#2196f3'],
    legend: 'none',
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        count: 0
      },
      textPosition: 'none'
    },
    series: {
      1: {
        lineWidth: 4,
        type: 'line'
      },
      2: {
        type: 'scatter'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function (sender) {
    var padding = 16;
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var containerBounds = chart.getContainer().getBoundingClientRect();

    for (var row = 0; row < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
      var pointBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('point#2#' + row);
      var dataLabel = document.createElement('span');
      dataLabel.className = 'data-label';
      dataLabel.innerHTML = 'Label ' + row;
      dataLabel.style.top = (containerBounds.top + pointBounds.top - (pointBounds.height / 2)) + 'px';
      dataLabel.style.left = (containerBounds.left + pointBounds.left + pointBounds.width + padding) + 'px';
      chart.getContainer().appendChild(dataLabel);
    }
  });

  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
});
```

```css
.data-label {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: More than help, you saved my day! Many many thanks for giving the right direction! Now I can imagine moving from Excel macros to a server side solution using Google Suite. If I may, do you know if it's possible to add a label just after the dots ?

Comment: it's possible, but not using standard options from google charts. if you use an annotation, it will place the label above. but you can add your own custom labels. and use chart methods to position next to dots. let me find an example...

Comment: Hello @WhiteHat, sorry for my late answer, but I had some busy days, and wanted absolutely to try by myself before answering to you. In my code I have another chart just on the left of the one proposed thanks to your code. The labels 
 are not displayed properly. They appear in the other chart but not on the wanted one. Is there a way to have relative coordinates to the current chart ?

Comment: not sure I follow, you're trying to add labels to the current chart, but they appear on the other?

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure about what I'm saying. I figured out to make it work now. The first time I refreshed the page (2 charts on a same row), I had the feeling the labels were displayed in absolute to the page and not to the chart frame. Anyway. It works now and would like to warmly thank you for your help. Of course, I mark this as solved! Thx!